# German coat of arms

Tags: germany, heraldry, hesse

I'm trying to find a good resource for researching German coat of arms.

Specifically I've traced my family `Zaun` back to the 1700s in Rothenditmold, Kassel, Hessen, Germany. [Archion](http://www.archion.de) has been my largest resource though I have used a few others.

Where should I turn to research the coat of arms? When I do a simple Google search for them I turn up a ton of sites that look like they are 20 years old and seem quite scammy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Johann Siebmacher](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Siebmacher) (de.wikipedia.org) published some early books on German coats of arms around 1600 (images from the book from 1605: [Wikimedia Commons: Siebmachers Wappenbuch](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Siebmachers_Wappenbuch)). His name was used in the 19th century for a book named *Neuer Siebmacher*, a collection of coat of arms that was still in reprint in the 20th century. The [website of Bernhard Peters](http://www.dr-bernhard-peter.de/Heraldik/seite53-sieb.htm) states that 130.000 different coat of arms were collected in 119 volumes. He lists a vast number of digital resources (digitized books).

The German association [*Herold*](http://www.herold-verein.de/index.php/de/) published a successor, the so-called *Deutsche Wappenrolle* (75 volumes so far).

If you have a good reason to believe that family Zaun had/has a coat of arms you should turn to a specialized message board like [heraldik-wappen.de](http://www.heraldik-wappen.de/) for further help.

The German Wikipedia entry on [Wappen (= coat of arms)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wappen#Literatur) has a lengthy bibliography on German heraldry.